# Is there a way to install applications using the text based UI that is presented during the OS installation?

Tags: system-installation, snap

During a installation of Ubuntu Server you are presented with a screen which has a list of applications you can check that will be installed.  For example, one of those applications is docker.  I believe these are called “snaps”.

Is there a way of installing these apps using the same GUI *after* you have installed the OS?

Answer (score 6):

You are talking about Subiquity installer. The screenshot of mentioned snap installation menu is below:

[image: Snaps]

The below message is contained in Subiquity's [source-code](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/77af962ab3aadb15b69b4108992221fb9b99c340/subiquity/ui/views/snaplist.py#L461).

> These are popular snaps in server environments. Select or deselect with SPACE, press ENTER to see more details of the package, publisher and versions available.

While the list of featured server snaps is contained in the [`server.section` file](https://github.com/canonical/section_ops/blob/master/prod/server.section). I compiled them to table below

| Snap name | Publisher | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| microk8s | canonical✓ | Kubernetes for workstations and appliances |
| nextcloud | nextcloud✓ | Nextcloud Server - A safe home for all your data |
| wekan | xet7 | The open-source kanban |
| kata-containers | katacontainers✓ | Build lightweight VMs that seamlessly plug into the containers ecosystem |
| docker | canonical✓ | Docker container runtime |
| canonical-livepatch | canonical✓ | Ubuntu Livepatch Client |
| rocketchat-server | rocketchat✓ | Rocket.Chat server |
| mosquitto | mospuitto✓ | Eclipse Mosquitto MQTT broker |
| etcd | canonical✓ | RResilient key-value store by CoreOS |
| powershell | microsoft-powershell✓ | PowerShell for every system! |
| stress-ng | cking-kernel-tools | ttool to load and stress a computer |
| sabnzbd | safihre | SABnzbd |
| wormhole | snapcrafters | get things from one computer to another, safely |
| aws-cli | aws✓ | UUniversal Command Line Interface for Amazon Web Services |
| google-cloud-sdk | google-cloud-sdk✓ | Google Cloud SDK |
| slcli | softlayer | PPython based SoftLayer API Tool. |
| doctl | digitalocean✓ | The official DigitalOcean command line interface |
| conjure-up | canonical✓ | PPackage runtime for conjure-up spells |
| postgresql10 | cmd✓ | PostgreSQL is a powerful, open source object-relational database system. |
| heroku | heroku✓ | CLI client for Heroku |
| keepalived | keepalived-project✓ | High availability VRRP/BFD and load-balancing for Linux |
| prometheus | canonical | TThe Prometheus monitoring system and time series database |
| juju | canonical✓ | Juju - a model-driven operator lifecycle manager for K8s and machines |
| maas | canonical✓ | Metal as a Service |

You can install any of them  using  `snap install snap-name`  command without any additional application.